# Area 51 site for technical documentation?

Tags: feature-request

I'm wondering if it would be better to split off technical writing from Writers? Well, I'm not *wondering*. I'd like to do it. Writers seems to be too broad for the type of questions I'd like to ask and answer. I had to filter out a lot of tags to find anything.

Anyway, I started a Technical Documentation site within Area 51, if anyone is interested in trying it instead of posting here. I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: I'd love to see more tech-writing questions here.  (It's my focus too. )  Please help build up that content on this site! What are some examples of questions you don't think you can ask here?

Answer (score 3):

Writers is having enough trouble reaching critical mass on its own; a site on only technical writing would have the same problem, but it would be even worse.

Also, people currently aren't clear if questions should be asked on Writers, English, or English Language Learners. Do we really want to add yet another site to that list?

I agree with Monica's comment: Let's encourage tech writing questions here.

What can we do to make this site more friendly to tech writers?